# How can I make a hyperref of an image?

Tags: hyperref, gif

My question is simple. I have to send a zip with pdfs and GIFS. Is there any way to *hyperref* the GIFs and open them from the pdf? They will be all in the same .zip
Thank you

Comment: Try with `\href{run:file.gif}{text}`.

Comment: In the pdf, it says that It is not possible to open the archive '.gif'. Do I have to write '*filename*.gif' ?

Comment: `file.gif` should be the name of the GIF file. So if you have `mylittlepony.gif`, then use `mylittlepony.gif`.

Comment: XD, yes it works, sorry if i didn't had answered before...

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
\href{run:file.gif}{text}
```

`file.gif` should be the name of the GIF file. So if you have `mylittlepony.gif`, then use `mylittlepony.gif`.

The command `run:` will issue the default program associated with `.gif` files on the local computer.